# can we make Drone with Dc 180 motor and Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, drone

I want to make a drone as a project for my university, But I am kinda newbie in this, I did many searches about this and I found I should do it with the brushless motors (BLDC) but I can't buy this kind of motors, So I want to do it with DC motors I found in youtube there is motor can be used in the drone it called ( 180 dc motor) but they didn't use them with Arduino.

My question is can I use Dc 180 motor with Arduino and make a drone Or Not?

Comment: https://youtu.be/J0x4ChjUS00 not exactly what u wanted but it is also using brushed motor if u want u can give this a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could but you will have to use a motor driver or else the motors will not be able to get enough power and try using arduino micro or an esp32 if you want to use it with Bluetooth which will also help you to keep the weight down.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but he didn't use Arduino he used transmitter and receiver, I want to connect it with my Arduino and my code and thank you aalot

Comment: Sorry your question didn't fully load on my phone I have updated my answer

Comment: So if I want connect it with Arduino i need 1. motor driver and micro And Nano will work too right? , and drone will work 100%? Thank you very much

Comment: Yes it will work with arduino Nano just try keeping the weight of the drone as less as possible and you can also use transistor insted of a motor driver I suggest watching this video : https://youtu.be/J0x4ChjUS00

Comment: maybe this is a dumb question, but what the point of using motor driver and transistor? yes thanks about the video

Comment: You have to use a transistor or a motor driver because an Arduino has a maximum output of 5v 40ma on its digital pins which is not enough for these motors. they are used to mainly supply voltage and current to the motors as the current input of the motors can go as high as 0.80amps

Comment: Thank you a lot